# Generate in flight string from [A-z]

Tags: python, random

I want to know what is a simplest way to write method which generates me number from 1 to 50, and then depends of generated number returns me string like:

`Abcdef` if generated number is 6
`Abcdefghi` if generated number is 9.

I'm using python 3.2

Comment: and if the rand number is > 26 (number of letter in the alphabets) ?

Comment: good question :) then 27 letter is a, 28 b and so on. Thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few approaches, the simplest:

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> string.ascii_letters[:random.randint(1, 50)].title()
'Abcdefghijklmnopq'
>>> string.ascii_letters[:random.randint(1, 50)].title()
'Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopq'
>>> string.ascii_letters[:random.randint(1, 50)].title()
'Abcdefghijklmnopqrs'
```

Or you can have a go with `itertools`:

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> from itertools import islice, cycle
>>> def randstr():
...     return ''.join(islice(cycle(string.ascii_lowercase),
...                           random.randint(1, 50))).title()
...
>>> randstr()
'Abcdefghijklmnopq'
>>> randstr()
'Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopq'
>>> randstr()
'Abcdefghijklmnopqrs'
```

Comment: I think you should add .title() because he want the first letter in upper case .

Comment: I have an exception: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'letters'

Comment: string.letters has been renamed to string.ascii_letters in Python 3.

Comment: Its actually better to use randrange and choice
+1 for itertools